# Smallish VBA Macro runs really Slow

Tags: vba, excel

My Macro that I wrote is running really slowly and I'm not sure why. The Macro deletes the area, then reproduces one column of locations as a row, deleting any duplicates, then copy's across a column of dates, then puts the corresponding Mean value for each date under the correct functional location.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro


' Delete Previous Data
Range("J1:AQ1000").Clear

' Functional Location

Dim toAdd As Boolean, uniqueTag As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Cells(1, 11).Value = Cells(2, 2).Value
uniqueTag = 11
toAdd = True
For i = 3 To 1000
For j = 11 To uniqueTag
If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(1, j).Value Then
toAdd = False
End If
Next j
If toAdd = True Then
Cells(1, uniqueTag + 1).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
uniqueTag = uniqueTag + 1
End If
toAdd = True
Next i

' Date

Dim k As Integer
For k = 2 To 1000
Cells(k, 10).Value = Cells(k, 6).Value
Next k

' Mean Value
Dim l As Integer, m As Integer
For l = 2 To 1000
For m = 11 To 100
If Cells(l, 2).Value = Cells(1, m).Value Then
Cells(l, m).Value = Cells(l, 5).Value
End If
Next m
Next l



End Sub
```

Are there any optimizations that would make it run faster, or something I haven't included? 
The first parts all work pretty speedily, its only the copying of the mean values which appears to take time.

Comment: If you have working code which merely needs improvements then you're probably in the wrong place with this post. [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is where they handle existing / working code and do their upmost to improve it in terms of speed, security, sustainability, and longevity including best-practices. Give it a try. They're good!

Comment: Thanks! I will post it there and hope for some help :D

Comment: practice loading the data into variant arrays then dumping it back into the worksheet. as it stands you have close to 100,000 potential transactions and comparisons. The mean calculations are almost 90,000 of these which explains their impact on the speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your code where I commented:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'----enter here all of your code----

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Wow, that made it instant!! Thanks so much, why does that make it so much faster?

Comment: @MinMorts You welcome. If my answer help you, please accept it. To understand why the code is most faster, please read this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498.aspx

Comment: For future VBA coding you might want to read-up on coding best practices as documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5925/switch-off-properties-during-macro-execution#t=201703101311474631047 @Marius suggestion is also part of it.